# C++ dynamic alocate, pointers

Tags: c++

**I get this error :**

> "crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer"

this program should write every second sign...

```
char x = 1;
while ( x != 0) {
    char *ptr(0);
    ptr = new char;
    fgets(ptr, 100001, stdin);

    for (char i = 0; i < sizeof(ptr); i++) {
        cout << *(ptr + i);
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete ptr;
    ptr = 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr = new char[10001];` ? or better, use `std::string`.

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)` is not what you expect neither.

Comment: i cant use string i can only write my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` returns size in bytes of the object representation of type. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

One other point major point to note is that `ptr = new char` will only allocate exactly one byte from the heap. But in your code you are trying to read 100001 bytes and obviously this is beyond the accessible memory range of that pointer.

you can modify the error as `ptr = new char[100001];` When you do this, there is another change that you must do in order to avoid memory leaks.

That being, `delete[] ptr`. Because you have allocated 100001 adjacent bytes, you have to de-allocate them all.

Answer (score 7):

`ptr = new char;` allocates **exactly** one byte for the pointer. Than `fgets(ptr, 100001, stdin);` attempts to read up to 100001 characters into it, obviously well beyond it's allocated boundary.

The immediate solution would be to make sure you allocate the buffer with adequate size using array form of `new`, i.e. `ptr = new char[100001];`. This, in turn, will lead to changing the `delete` into it's array form as well: `delete[] ptr`

Also, keep in mind that `sizeof(ptr)` will give you the size of the pointer (4 or 8 bytes on most platforms). You would want to use `strlen` or similar to find out when the string ends.

All suggestions above should be taken in light of the learning exercise. In real life, you should not do this, and instead use `std::string` and modern ways of string-oriented reading. (`std::getline` would be the most readily available).